Book copy/paste on Stack Overflow and AI policy?
Case
During my review of this First answer. I thought the answer was AI generated. But according to the comments this is a retyping of a book.
While this answer is technically not AI it has severe issues:

Target C++23 while the question is about C++20
Answer for GCC first while the question is about MSVC
It's more about personal taste, but answer is too big and abuse of bold formatting

The first issue make it technically a non-answer, although someone understanding C++ can easily workaround that, someone understanding C++ would have made the answer for C++20 before posting and at least put MSVC in first position, the poster clearly did no effort to adapt the book citation to the question.
My thoughts
Why I am talking about AI?
Because I honestly thought it was AI.
I feel like the answer poster have exaggerated trust in their book like someone can do so with an AI without critical thinking.
Also when reading the StackOverflow policy about AI I found excerpt I highlighted which match the issues of this answer:

Users who ask questions on Stack Overflow expect to receive an answer authored and vetted by a human. This ensures that the answer is factual, relevant, and complete, up to the standards of another human. While human authors are not perfect, generative artificial intelligence tools may not take into account other important factors to a question (e.g., optimization, security, etc.), often add excessive noise to their answers (e.g., explaining all details, no matter how relevant), and may fabricate false or misleading information.


Searching for sources, synthesizing them into a good answer, and referencing them clearly are critical steps in developing a well-crafted answer.


Remember - the person who asked a question needs a correct answer. As such, answering correctly is always more important than answering quickly. [...]

I cannot check myself if this is truly a book copy/paste. But even if true, I believe this answer is an AI quality answer as it has many of AI answers issues.
In the four first comments we had me and the answer poster (before any edit maybe), they will not be fix their answer and told me to buy a book exactly meant for C++20 I case I needed C++20.
Talking about copyright, I am not familiar with fair-use but there is much more than necessary citation, like a whole page. (edit:) Although the source has been clearly cited in the answer.
What I want?
Your thoughts! I am a little user who think he found a case that merit thinking about, trusting a book so much is look like trusting an AI. Perhaps some edit of Stack Overflow help pages may be good?
Given my modest involvement on Stack Overflow, I am on the questioning side. I have made my argument that this is informally an AI answer and would like to have your inputs, reactions, and opinion on this case.

Looks like it should be deleted though, I don't think there's any original content in the answer, which is against the guidelines for using external content.

What if the BOOK was AI Generated? Lot of that going around these days.

JSYK - Answers that are in the wrong language are, by SO policy, not NAA.

"trusting a book so much is look like trusting an AI" - it's all part of the same mistake - referencing only one source. You should always cross-reference when in doubt. If you don't do that, you end up posting a Stack Overflow question with a lessened chance of success. But at least they're reading a book and not relying only on random free online tutorials or videos, that shows a willingness to use higher quality sources.

You have flagged that answer with NAA flag.
Even though the flag was automatically marked helpful because OP deleted their answer, it was the wrong flag to use in this case as it was clearly attempt to answer. See When to flag an answer as "not an answer"
If you suspect that content of an answer is plagiarized or it is not properly quoted then you should use dedicated plagiarism flag. See Plagiarism flag and moderator tooling has launched to Stack Overflow!
If you suspect that post is AI generated, then you should use custom mod flag where  you would state that and add reasons why you think it is AI generated. Stating reasons is not necessary, but they can be helpful.

Yes; Thank You this is the correct response and guidance for plagiarized content

Right. I will choose a better flag next time. I also edited my question to include that the book have been properly referenced so it is not plain plagiarism in this case.

I wouldn't have suspected this to be AI, given it's rather poorly written/organized, not wordy enough, and has too much additional formatting to be what we generally see from AI.
So, with the above, and working under the assumption that it isn't AI... it's just a low quality answer and we have a tool for that on the left side.
There are certainly parallels between copy pasting an AI output and copy pasting from another source, but, we've always allowed properly attributed 3rd party content.
(I'm not commenting on whether or not this case is properly attributed.)

Wouldn’t copying and pasting from a book or other source be plagiarism, which is something that isn’t allowed, so regardless if it was AI or plagiarism the answer should have been instantly deleted and the author reminded of our policies surrounding plagiarism and GenAI?

Yes, @SecurityHound, if it is copy-pasted from a book without attribution, then that would be plagiarism, and the post should be flagged as such. I think the point is that AI is a red herring here.

We aren't going to handle something as if it were AI-generated simply because it feels like "AI quality". There are significant consequences for users who post AI generated content which would be simply unfair otherwise.
It sounds from your description (I didn't look into the details, and probably wouldn't be familiar with the purported source material anyway) like this answer might fall afoul of plagiarism policy, which is also taken seriously.
In general we aren't too fussed about the publicly-stated reasons why questions are closed, and deleted answers often won't have such a reason even for 10k+ users. However, it's important to be precise in cases where the user might need to be penalized.

Please note that the fact that it targets the wrong version of C++ is not a valid reason to flag the question. See the following posts:

Are blatantly wrong answers very low quality?
Are answers that completely ignore the explicit constraints of the question Very Low Quality?
Are answers which misunderstood the question low quality?

That being said, the fact that it's targeting the wrong version of C++ might be a reason to downvote (if it diminishes the usefulness of the post) and/or comment pointing out the error, but typically no further action is required beyond that. Flags should not be used for inaccurate content.
On the other hand, the fact that it's taken verbatim from a book might be a reason to flag. If the poster didn't cite it properly, that would be considered plagiarism.
